# CSS Footer image

Tags: css, footer, html

I have the following code which works great with creating a background and a header, but it doesn't put in the footer as intended. How do I fix this?

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(banner.png), url(filler.png), url(footer.png);
    background-position: center top, center center, center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y, no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Here's the result of the above code: http://puu.sh/7jgq8.jpg
The header and background filler functions as intended, but no footer.

Comment: Are you sure that the image footer.png is available?

Comment: Positive, when I replace the banner.png with the footer.png, it will load up the footer image in its place. Then it won't put the banner at the bottom, so I assume it's some sort of error on my part? For example: [image](http://puu.sh/7jh9K.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder your elements and combine with the suggestion from [loop_duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493544/loop-duplicate).

You've specified `banner`, `filler`, `footer`. As such `footer` is written over by `filler`. Switch to `banner`, `footer`, `filler` and you'll be able to see the footer.

```
<style>
html, body {
    min-height: 100%
}
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(banner.png), url(footer.png), url(filler.png);
    background-position: center top, center bottom, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `<body>` element is extending to the bottom of the page:

```
html, body {
   min-height: 100%
}
```

Comment: I attempted this, but I guess I'm not sure where it's supposed to go. I put it inside the <body> tags, inside <style> tags within the body, inside the body{} setup that I have above, but none of it works. Sorry, I'm new to web dev

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: center top, center center, center bottom;
```

center bottom makes your image to take bottom of window not document

I think you are looking for something like this [Sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) or [bootstrap sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)